# Two different ways to make javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and now studying it...

```
var person = function() {
    this.name = "name"
};

var person2 = function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = "name";
    return obj;
};
```

Let's suppose we have two functions shown above. It seems that objects can be created by using either of the functions. For example)

```
var p = new person();
var p2 = new person2();
```

My question is: What's difference between person vs person2? Are they exactly the same? If not which one is a more preferable way to use?

Thanks

Comment: The first once is a constructor function, the second one is just a function returning an object and could also be called without `new`. There is a difference, which should become clearer when you read about `new`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.

Comment: @FelixKling Except it *is* called with `new`, which changes things.

Comment: @Andrew: Not really because the function *explicitly* returns an object. Calling it with or without `new` won't make a difference. (of course it makes a difference in so far that `this` will refer to different values inside the function, but it doesn't make a difference for the result of the function call).

Comment: @Momo: That's totally unrelated.

Comment: Note that `var p2 = {name: "name"};` is basically the same as the second way.

Comment: @FelixKling What I was getting at is, that while it doesn’t make a difference in this specific case, what’s actually happening is different. For example, if you return something other than an object. Or, as you say, you explicitly return an object while also modifying `this`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `this` will be garbage collected at the end of the function if you return an _Object_.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It *technically* makes a difference in this specific case if you're doing more obscure things. For example, `p.constructor` and `p2.constructor` are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way of creating an object is the first way.

The second way will create two objects, and one will be discarded. One object will be created before the function is called, just as with the first method, but because the function returns another object the first object will be discarded and the returned object will be used instead.

An important difference between the methods is that the second one can't use a prototype. Anything that you put in the prototype of the function will be applied to the object that ends up being discarded.

Comment: I disagree with that the first way is normal. I think the normal way is `var p2 = {name: "name"};`, possibly with the object returned by a function if it's used in multiple places.

Comment: @PeterOlson: That's the normal way of using the `new` keyword. If you don't want to do that, that's a completely different matter.

Comment: I agree with you there, but I think it's misleading to say it's the normal way of creating an object.

Comment: @PeterOlson: In what way do you think that it's misleading?

Comment: @PeterOlson It is a normal way of creating an object from a custom constructor. I assume OP has more logic in that constructor that requires more than a plain object.

Comment: @Guffa Becase "creating an object" does not mean "using the `new` keyword". Somebody might read the post and think that using an object literal to create an object is not "the normal way". @Fabrico There's not very many things that require a custom constructor. Pretty much anything you can do with a constructor you can do with a plain object.

Comment: @Guffa what do you mean by second one "can't use a prototype" ? Its kinda confusing.

Comment: @PeterOlson: The object system in Javascript is prototype based, and to use that you use the new keyword to create objects. You can also create objects using an object literal, but that is only used to create "flat" objects without a prototype. You don't need to use prototypes if you don't like to, but it's definitely the normal way to create objects in Javascript.

Comment: @woofmeow: Anything that you put in the prototype of the function will be applied to the object that is created using the new keyword, but with the second method that object is discarded. The object returned from the function won't have anything from the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the way you use the functions.

The first one is intended to be used as a *constructor*, `this` being set to the newly created object. It is intended to be used in combination with the operator `new`, as follows:

```
var bill = new person();
```

This is just like a normal constructor as in typical OOP language.

---

The second one is intended to be used as a normal function (without `new`), e.g.:

```
var bill = person();
```

You can use this way of object creation in combination with the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: Worth noting that the 2nd one does not inherit from the constructor's prototype (obvious, but a notable change).